# Unset special price for product via magmi

Tags: price, magmi

I want to remove the special price from some products that have special price. I've tried to leave the column empty but then the special price was updated to 0 what can I do to simply remove the price from some products via magmi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use **__MAGMI_DELETE__** magic value to force magmi removing a value entry.

This magic value works for all values you want to "unset"

Comment: thnaks that worked flawlessly :)

Comment: hi @dweeves, where do I put it (__MAGMI_DELETE__) / how to use it ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your value for special price defaults to 0.

Try this. On the backend go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes. Locate special price. Set "Values Required" to no and leave the "default value" blank. Then just update your products. If I understand your problem that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but that's already was my settings in the attribute

Comment: When you import are you using 0 for special price if there isn't a special price or are you just leaving it blank?